# Looking for instructions to Mega Bloks "Blok Bots" sets

Tags: instructions, clone-brands

I need instructions for Mega Bloks "Blok Bots" set 9375.  I have parts for another one, but I don't know which one. If I get instructions for 1 or 2 sets I'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for the set you are looking for can be found here:

https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9375.pdf

Here are some instructions for some other sets from that series:

- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9392.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9391.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9374.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9371.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9344.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9343.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9341.pdf
- https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9331.pdf

For whatever reason, the availability of instructions for these sets is inconsistent.

Comment: "page not found"